# How can I load my AWS EC2 Key pair PEM file to my terratest script to perform AWS EC2 SSH connection validation

Tags: go, amazon-ec2, terraform, key-pair, terratest

I am writing Go terratest script to validate SSH connection for AWS EC2 instance

I already have AWS EC2 keypair PEM file in my local

I am able to launch and destroy EC2 instance using terraform.TgApplyAll() and terraform.TgDestroyAll() methods and fetch the output variables using terraform.Output() method

My local AWS EC2 keypair PEM file is used for creating EC2 instance in AWS

Now I am trying to validate SSH connection Programmatically from terratest Go script.

I am **NOT** able to load my local AWS EC2 Key pair to **sshKeyPair**  variable in Go terratest script

I used below code snippet but no use

https://github.com/gruntwork-io/module-asg/blob/067647b3aaeb24151badbc5a2d9a6b5381dd2041/test/server_group_test.go#L78

I also tried script present in at
https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/907c09f0696083a5ada580debb66bb5c00c19c32/modules/test-structure/save_test_data.go#L66  to load my local EC2 key pair using LoadEc2KeyPair and test EC2 SSH using **fmt.Sprintf("SSH to public host %s", publicIP)**
But getting error while reading EC2 keypair from local in **LoadTestData(t testing.TestingT, path string, value interface{})** method at **json.Unmarshal(bytes, value)** built in call

*Error message :
Failed to parse JSON for value D:\AWS\KeyPair\pandukeypair.pem: invalid character '-' in numeric literal
I am getting this error as I am trying to ream .pem file and code is trying to do json.umarshal on the .pem file*

All code snippets available in github/terratest modules talks about creating **new** keypair and loading AWS EC2 **JSON** keypair as  but i am not getting any approach/Logic for my scenario where already **existing** keypair JSON is present I just want to load and use it.

Full Code is present in below link

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dl2mpesidsxitdu/AAAOi4Nmp41CHMSPcyU7a2qva?dl=0

Comment: A couple of terminology comments: 1. The language is called "Go", not "GoLang". 2. There's no such thing as a "Go script", because Go is compiled, and scripts, by definition, are interpreted.

Comment: Aside from that, your question is incomplete. You've provided a link to some code we can't see. Even if we could see it, all relevant code is required to be _in the question_, because links tend to go bad.

Comment: code that reproduces the problem.  that's how make sense of this stuff

Comment: Can you share your code of _test.go file of ssh test using terratest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using below Code snippet/functio ..

GenerateRSAKeyPairE:
func RSAKeyPairFromFile(fpath string) (*terrassh.KeyPair, error) {
// import crypto/x509
// import `enter code here`io/ioutil
// import encoding/pem
// import "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
// terrassh "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/ssh"

```
pemBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fpath)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
pemBlock, _ := pem.Decode(pemBytes)
if pemBlock == nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to decode PEM block containing private key")
}
privKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(pemBlock.Bytes)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
sshPubKey, err := ssh.NewPublicKey(privKey.Public())
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
sshPubKeyBytes := ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey(sshPubKey)
sshPubKeyStr := string(sshPubKeyBytes)
return &terrassh.KeyPair{PublicKey: sshPubKeyStr, PrivateKey: string(pemBytes)}, nil
```

}